# Fullscreen bootstrap 4 card with highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, bootstrap-4, fullscreen

I have several (bootstrap) cards where I would like to have the opportunity to show this fullscreen. Highcharts charts are present in these cards. The problem is that the height of the highcharts does not adapt when you are going in full screen mode.

A while ago I asked the same question with bootstrap panels and then "daniel_s" made this example for panels. Only now I have added a number of columns at the bottom and it has been converted from panels to cards. Unfortunately the example is not working anymore. Again "daniel_s" made an example but the height is still not 100%.

Is there a possibility to automatically adjust the scaling of the highcharts so that the ratio (columns at the bottom and header) remains the same as in this example?

In addition, I would also like to know how I get the header the text and icons on one line. So that the text is on the left and the icons are on the right.

HTML

```
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<!------ Include the above in your HEAD tag ---------->

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-3">
      <div class="card with-margin card_shadow card_border rounded">
        <div class="container-fluid" id="mainContainer">
          <div class="row border-bottom-0 card_border2" style="background: linear-gradient(to right, #eea849, #fa7921); justify-content: space-between">
            <h3>Panel 1</h3>
            <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#" id="panel-fullscreen" class="fullscreen-btn" role="button" title="Toggle fullscreen"><i class="fas fa-expand"></i></a></li>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="card-body border-top-0 border-bottom-0 card_border2 row-200">
              <div id="container"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row bg-white justify-content-center card_border">
            <div class="col-sm text-center card_border2">
              <br> text 1
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm text-center card_border2">
              <br> text 2
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm text-center card_border2">
              <br> text 3
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm text-center card_border2">
              <br> text 4
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-3">
      <div class="card with-margin card_shadow card_border rounded">
        <div class="container-fluid" id="mainContainer">
          <div class="row border-bottom-0 card_border2" style="background: linear-gradient(to right, #eea849, #fa7921); justify-content: space-between">
            <h3>Panel 2</h3>
            <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#" id="panel-fullscreen2" class="fullscreen-btn" role="button" title="Toggle fullscreen"><i class="fas fa-expand"></i></a></li>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="card-body border-top-0 border-bottom-0 card_border2 row-200">
              <div id="container2"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row bg-white justify-content-center card_border">
            <div class="col-sm text-center card_border2">
              <br> text 1
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm text-center card_border2">
              <br> text 2
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm text-center card_border2">
              <br> text 3
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm text-center card_border2">
              <br> text 4
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.panel-actions {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  text-align: right;
}

.panel-actions a {
  color: #333;
}
#mainContainer {
  height: 50%;
}
.panel-fullscreen {
  display: block;
  z-index: 9999;
  position: fixed !important;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}
.full-height-row {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
#container {
  height: 100%;
}
#container2 {
  height: 100%;
}
.row-200 {
  height: 220px;
}

.card_border {
  border: solid 0.75px #fa7921;
}

.card_border2 {
  border: solid 2px #fa7921;
}
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var charts = [];
  var chart1Info = {
    containerId: "container",
    definition: {
      title: {
        text: "Chart1 Title"
      },
      subtitle: {
        text: "Source: thesolarfoundation.com"
      },
      yAxis: {
        title: {
          text: "Number of Employees"
        }
      },
      legend: {
        layout: "vertical",
        align: "right",
        verticalAlign: "middle"
      },
      plotOptions: {
        series: {
          label: {
            connectorAllowed: false
          },
          pointStart: 2010
        }
      },
      series: [
        {
          name: "Installation",
          data: [43934, 52503, 57177, 69658, 97031, 119931, 137133, 154175]
        },
        {
          name: "Manufacturing",
          data: [24916, 24064, 29742, 29851, 32490, 30282, 38121, 40434]
        },
        {
          name: "Sales & Distribution",
          data: [11744, 17722, 16005, 19771, 20185, 24377, 32147, 39387]
        },
        {
          name: "Project Development",
          data: [null, null, 7988, 12169, 15112, 22452, 34400, 34227]
        },
        {
          name: "Other",
          data: [12908, 5948, 8105, 11248, 8989, 11816, 18274, 18111]
        }
      ]
    }
  };
  var chart2Info = {
    containerId: "container2",
    definition: {
      title: {
        text: "Chart2 Title"
      },
      subtitle: {
        text: "Source: thesolarfoundation.com"
      },
      yAxis: {
        title: {
          text: "Number of Employees"
        }
      },
      legend: {
        layout: "vertical",
        align: "right",
        verticalAlign: "middle"
      },
      plotOptions: {
        series: {
          label: {
            connectorAllowed: false
          },
          pointStart: 2010
        }
      },
      series: [
        {
          name: "Installation",
          data: [43934, 52503, 57177, 69658, 97031, 119931, 137133, 154175]
        },
        {
          name: "Manufacturing",
          data: [24916, 24064, 29742, 29851, 32490, 30282, 38121, 40434]
        },
        {
          name: "Sales & Distribution",
          data: [11744, 17722, 16005, 19771, 20185, 24377, 32147, 39387]
        },
        {
          name: "Project Development",
          data: [null, null, 7988, 12169, 15112, 22452, 34400, 34227]
        },
        {
          name: "Other",
          data: [12908, 5948, 8105, 11248, 8989, 11816, 18274, 18111]
        }
      ]
    }
  };

  function drawChart(chartInfo) {
    // Properties that vary by chart should be defined in chartInfo
    // Any properties that are the same for all charts are added here
    chartInfo.responsive = {
      rules: [
        {
          condition: {
            maxWidth: 500
          },
          chartOptions: {
            legend: {
              layout: "horizontal",
              align: "center",
              verticalAlign: "bottom"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    };

    if (chartInfo == chart1Info) {
      charts[0] = Highcharts.chart(chartInfo.containerId, chartInfo.definition);
    } else {
      charts[1] = Highcharts.chart(chartInfo.containerId, chartInfo.definition);
    }
  }
  //Toggle fullscreen
  $(".fullscreen-btn").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var $this = $(this);
    $this
      .children("i")
      .toggleClass("fa-expand")
      .toggleClass("fa-arrows-alt");
    $(this)
      .closest(".card")
      .toggleClass("panel-fullscreen");
    $($(this).parents()[3])
      .find(".card-body")
      .toggleClass("row-200");

    var chartInfo =
      $this.attr("id") === "panel-fullscreen" ? chart1Info : chart2Info;
    drawChart(chartInfo);
  });

  drawChart(chart1Info);
  drawChart(chart2Info);
});
```

As can be seen in this [example](https://codepen.io/Lodewijk/full/eardrb), the height is not 100%, while in this [example](https://codepen.io/Lodewijk/full/oMEMXm/) the height is 100%. How do I manage that in the first example the height is always 100%.

Comment: You've used `highcharts` label but this issue seems to be related to bootstrap structure and styles only and not with highcharts itself.

Comment: The reason that I combine bootstrap with highcharts is that highcharts must be redrawed again to get the alignment right. So it's about the combination of highcharts with bootstrap.

Comment: On your example, I've noticed that the container (with a chart and other HTML elements) doesn't fit the whole screen. That's why I think the problem is with bootstrap and CSS styles because the chart itself has a proper height.

Comment: I think you are right, but I do not know which elements are incorrect, because in the second example the alignment is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've examined both examples and probably found the solution.

1. In your working example, all the elements are located in one container `panel` which has a height set to 100% and child `panel-heading` of height 94%.
2. In your example with the issue, there is a 'card' with height set to 100% and child `container-fluid` with `rows` inside without a fixed height set.

So as you can see rows doesn't know how to share the space on the screen. To fix it you have to set the CSS styles so that `container-fluid` is 100% height and rows for example 10% top row, 80% middle row, 10% bottom row. Then all the elements are rendered correctly as you can see below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Wojciech Chmiel, I have processed your changes in this [example](https://codepen.io/Lodewijk/pen/JqBRKB). The fullscreen now works perfectly, only in 'normal view' there is an unnecessary bar visible under the container. This is caused by setting the row height to 80%. I tried to put the row height on the card body (panel 2) only then the height in both the normal view and fullscreen is not good. Do you know a possibility to remove the unnecessary space under card-body (panel 1)?

Comment: You should set the height of 80% only when a full-screen view is active. So it should be controlled using js.

Comment: Finally, after a few changes, I finally managed to get fullscreen working. Thank you for this!

Comment: I'm glad to hear that!